# Как по маске выводить нужный формат времени?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Нужно в зависимости по маске подставлять нужные ключи из объекта

`'d.m.Y H:i:s'` в return выводить уже в нужно формате.

Как такое реализовать?

```js
function datetime(mask = 'd.m.y h:i:s', time = false){

    let now = time ? new Date(time) : new Date();

    let data = {
        d: ('0'+ now.getDate()).slice(-2),
        m: ('0'+ (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
        y: now.getFullYear(),
        h: ('0'+ now.getHours()).slice(-2),
        i: ('0'+ now.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
        s: ('0'+ now.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
    }

    return data;
}

setInterval(()=>{
    $('.datetime').html(datetime('d.m.y h:i:s'));
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datetime"></div>
```

Comment: [Moment.js](https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format)? Также поддерживает разные локали.

Comment: @XelaNimed, без библиотек

Comment: данную задачу можно банально решить используя метод replace строки.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Если символы в маске совпадают с именами ключей, то этим и воспользуемся (разделители изменены для примера):

```js
function datetime(mask = 'd.m.y h:i:s', time = false) {

  let now = time ? new Date(time) : new Date();

  let data = {
    d: ('0' + now.getDate()).slice(-2),
    m: ('0' + (now.getMonth() + 1)).slice(-2),
    y: now.getFullYear(),
    h: ('0' + now.getHours()).slice(-2),
    i: ('0' + now.getMinutes()).slice(-2),
    s: ('0' + now.getSeconds()).slice(-2)
  }

  return [...mask].reduce((acc, el) => {
    return acc += data[el] || el;
  }, '');
}

setInterval(() => {
  $('.datetime').html(datetime('d/m*y h:i_s')); // Разделители изменены для примера
}, 1000);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="datetime"></div>
```

Если ключ соответствующий текущему символу маски отсутствует или отсутствует его значение, то символ подставляется "как есть".